# How to map a Firebird Smallint to Boolean with Hibernate Annotations?

Tags: hibernate, firebird, hibernate-annotations

I've an old database running in Firebird 2.0, and I need to map a SmallInt column to a Boolean  type, which when `SmallInt = 0` then is `False`, and when `SmallInt = 1` it's `True`.

I also need that this be done using Hibernate Annotations.

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After search a little bit more, I could find this hibernate type `org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType` on http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic

And I tried to map in this way:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private Boolean field;
```

But, this didn't work, because Hibernate throwed this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in %TABLE_NAME% for column %COLUMN_NAME%. Found: smallint, expected: integer
```

So, I tried to force the definition of this column, mapping in this way:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "SMALLINT")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private Boolean field;
```

And now this works like a charm.